# Yii2 UrlManager — почему не подставляются необязательные параметры?

Tags: yii2

Использую фреймворк Yii2.

В конфигурации есть правило для UrlManager'а:

```
....
'components' => [
    ...
    'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ...
                [
                    'pattern' => '<some-param>/some-page',
                    'route' => 'some/route',
                    'defaults' => ['some-param' => 'default-value']
               ],
                ...
            ]
        ],
    ...
]
....
```

В коде, во многих местах используется этот роут:
    echo Html::a('Some page', ['some/route']);

Но вместо формирования ссылки с дефолтным параметром:
default-value/some-page
формируется не правильная ссылка:
some/route

Вопрос: Для чего в rules можно прописывать defaults если они не подставляются при формировании ссылок?

По идее defaults значения для этого и нужны, что если где то при формировании ссылки не указаны параметры, значит надо поставить дефолтные значения.

Answer (score 1):

Рулесы отрабатываются правильно. По дефолту он не выводит роуты

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#parameterizing-routes

Нужно сделать еще одно правило для дефолтных роутов